# Python linking strings together in list

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a wordsearch for a school project and have hit a snag. I am using a class with functions for the board. Here is my code:

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self,size=20):
        self.board = [['']*size]*size
        self.board[0][0] = 'A'
        self.words = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet',\
                      'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit', 'quisque',\
                      'in', 'augue', 'sit', 'amet', 'est', 'ullamcorper',\
                      'bibendum', 'sed', 'at', 'arcu', 'nullam']
        self.clues = self.words

board = Board()
print ''.join(board.board[0])
print ''.join(board.board[1])
```

Instead of printing out the expected ('' = nothing)

```
A
''
```

It prints out

```
A
A
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a duplicate but I can never remember the question title

Comment: “Note also that the copies are shallow; nested structures are not copied. This often haunts new Python programmers” http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This creates a list of references to the same list

```
self.board = [['']*size]*size
```

You need to make a new list for each entry like this

```
self.board = [['']*size for x in range(size)]
```

It's only safe to multiply **immutable objects** across a list like this. Eg

```
['']*size
[0]*size
```

Since you are forced to *replace* the entries rather than modify them